# Storing information entered - Python

Tags: python, file, collections, external

recently I have been practicing with Python and have come up with a simple script which allows students to be entered along with their grades. However, I would like to be able to save the information entered to an external .txt file but I am not sure how to do this.

Heres my code:

```
results = []

print ("\n")
print ("=============================================================================")
print ("\n")
Institution = str(input("Please Enter the Name of Your Institution: "))

while True:
   print ("\n")
   print ("---------------------------------NEW STUDENT---------------------------------")
   print ("\n")
   print ("Please Enter the Current Year of the Students Course")
   Year = int(input("(For Example, Year '1 / 2 / 3 / 4'): "))
   print ("\n")
   print ("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
   print ("\n")
   Student = str(input("Student Full Name: "))
   print ("\n")
   ID = int(input("Student ID Number: "))
   print ("\n")
   print ("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
   print ("\n")
   Grade1 = int(input("Enter Student's First Term Grade: "))
   Grade2 = int(input("Enter Student's Second Term Grade: "))
   Grade3 = int(input("Enter Student's Third Term Grade: "))
   Grade4 = int(input("Enter Student's Fourth Term Grade: "))

   average =  (Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4)/4

   print ("\n")
   print ("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
   print ("\n")
   print ("Total Grade Average: %G" % (average))

   passed_or_failed = "PASSED"
   if average < 40:
     passed_or_failed = 'FAILED'
   results.append(passed_or_failed)

   print ("\n")
   print ("%s has: %s" % (Student, passed_or_failed))
   print ("\n")

  cont = input('Do you want to keep entering students? Y/N: ')

   if cont.lower() == "n":
      print ("\n")
      print ("----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
      print ("\n")
      print ("Thank you for using FinalGrade. Goodbye.")
      break
```

Would this be possible, at all? I was told about using collections to write to file however I am finding it difficult to work out how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: do you want save it every loop or at the end of it?

Comment: This is not a good SO question; start by [rtfm](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: @z4r Preferably the end? As long as all information from each "student" is stored I dont mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use :

```
with open('name_of_the_txt_file.txt','a') as fp: 
    fp.write("%s has: %s  " % (Student,passed_or_failed))
```

More information :
http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html 7.2

Comment: Where in my code would I be adding this? Sorry if this seems dumb, Im extremely new to python

Comment: Here is a pastebin link to help you. http://pastebin.com/4MVtQnVa

Comment: Hi, I tried what you just supplied me with but now I get syntax errors :( Any reason for this? @Alkis

Comment: Post the syntax errors you are getting

Comment: IDLE highlights the following "cont" line and states theres a syntax error, when I try to run the script :(

Comment: Oh it was just a small error , try this http://pastebin.com/vXsRJtvU

Comment: Ah, this works great now, thank you so much! One more question, it seems to store the results in the text file as one continuous line, is there any way to make it so a new line is created for each student?

Comment: Ok. This is super simple but its best not to chat through the comment section.Thus , find me on facebook : https://www.facebook.com/stasinos98

Comment: If you don't have facebook try this : http://pastebin.com/HWz24DRt

Comment: Was just about to add you however your second link helped greatly, thank you so much for all the help! @Alkis

Answer (score 0):

Organize your data as dictionary of named tuples
from collections import namedtuple

```
Student = namedtuple('Student', "id grades")
students = dict()
< get your data here>
student[<student name>] = Student(id, [grades])
```

Then you can save *students* and restore as an object with a simple [json module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) - just use *dump* and *load* calls